# How to determine if conventional electronics circuit is a better choice over a MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, microprocessor, production

I am a software engineer and have limited experience with conventional circuitry. Recently, I have built a prototype device that uses an Arduino Uno, a Bluetooth module, an array of temperature/humidity sensors, and an OLED readout display, which currently relies on I2C. The function of my device is to simply wait to receive a BT signal, which wakes it from low power, then enables data acquisition by the temp. sensors for a fixed length of time while averaging at each read interval, and then displaying the averaged temp. & humid values on the OLED.

Ultimately, I am trying to determine if can move away from the ATmega328p chip and design a MCU-less circuit with conventional electronics for a production model. My project objectives motivating this idea are: achieving lower material and labor costs and eliminating the dependence on software and firmware. Both are equally important to me. However, I do not know if I am creating other substantial obstacles for myself in doing so. How can I determine 1) if what I’m asking is even possible to do given the functional requirements of my device and 2) if it’s the right choice going the MCU-less approach based off my project objectives?

Comment: MCUs are being pretty conventional for decades. Anyway, having BT implies a usage of *some* MCU anyway. You can get some better suited MCU with integrated BT though for your purposes.

Comment: Might have misunderstood the requirements but what you describe without MCU/etc sounds practically unfeasible. I mean, you need I2C, Bluetooth, low power/sleep, etc right?

Comment: OLED display, BT and so on are going to require either an MCU or equivalent implemented in some (extremely complex) manner. Forget about MCU-less and choose *which* MCU.

Comment: If the task has multiple disparate steps, go MCU. Your entire first paragraph = multiple disparate steps.

Comment: $1 Pic uC can do this.

Comment: @Wesley Lee those are needed but I2C is just the protocol I’m currently using with my particular OLED.

Comment: Sounds like from several comments that the first part of my question, regarding MCU-less design, is essentially not possible and likely much more tasking to accomplish than what it’s worth?

Comment: Bluetooth is software. You can't do it without MCU.

Comment: You can also use an FPGA, but the complexity of all your used protocols stays. This subtracts the MCU, but adds the complex logic device. -- You can build a prototype **with** an MCU, and then look at the program. If it seems to be realizable by a similar digital logic, you can try that route.

Comment: @thebusybee this is exactly it. Aside from the BT and OLED protocols in my code, EVERYTHING else is if/then states with some specific delays and very minimal arithmetic. Strong state-machine type of behavior which has me wondered about a more conventional approach

Comment: @BryanA. The FPGA approach is totally defeating every single point from the *"My project objectives motivating this idea are: achieving lower material and labor costs and eliminating the dependence on software and firmware."*

Comment: Well, complexity in protocols leads to a lot of logic. Whether this is a state machine like the processor of an MCU with its program, or a programmed state machine in an FPGA, or a state machine built from a lot of simpler digital ICs, in the end it's all similarly complex. -- From the number of gates, I'd estimate that discrete logic has the lowest, followed by a just big enough MCU, with the FPGA at the top. -- From the effort to realize, it starts with the MCU as the lowest, followed by the FPGA, and the discrete logic at the top. -- It's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could reduce the part count by getting an IC that has bluetooth and a microcontroller in on IC (there are some to look at [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3320)) which are becoming more prevalent on the market right now.

It wouldn't be a MCU-less circuit necessarily because the MCU and the bluetooth module would be combined.

Comment: With BT is there no real way of integrating it without some sort of MCU. I am quite unfamiliar with the inner workings of BT. Maybe worth some time to understand...

Comment: The modules make it easy in many cases  with AT commands instead of needing to write software

Comment: @VoltageSpike I think you may have a mistranslation or an auto-correct mistake in your comment

Comment: Woah, yeah, that is not what I intended! You never know what your phone is going to throw out when you use voice commands! I missed it because there was another error that I corrected, definitely editing that comment